# Problems with zooming in HTML using Tooltip and Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, transform

I needed to change the zoom in my CSS to 90%, so the Tooltips completely lost their correct positions in the elements.

To understand better, if you go to the Tooltip website in the Bootstrap 5 documentation and run this script below, you will see that even on that page the Tooltip is in the wrong position, I need help to correct this.

[documentation Tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/)

Script to run in the browser console:

```
  // Destroy the tooltips
  var tooltipList = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(document.body);
  if (tooltipList) {
    tooltipList.dispose();
  }
  // Zoom to 90%
  document.body.style.zoom = '90%';
  // Start tooltips again
  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
  tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
  });
```

Even if I just zoom, the same thing happens.

Here is my CSS, I have already used zoom and transform:scale, both in 'html' and 'body'

```
html {
  zoom: 0.9; 
  zoom: 90%;
  width: 111.11vw; 
  min-height: 111.11vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: In my browser they show up in the correct positions, on the tooltip documentation page. Are you saying that even on the official docs page they render wrong in your browser?

Comment: If I run the document.body.style.zoom = '90%' command in the Chrome, Edge or Brave browser console, even on the documentation page, it is out of position. Using Firefox, this command does not reduce the screen size, so use document.body.style.transform = 'scale(0.9)' and after reducing the screen size, it will be out of position too.

Not just on my computer, anyone else who accesses a page with zoom reduction via code has this Tooltip positioning problem

Comment: From what I looked up on `document.body.style.zoom` after reading your last comment, its "non standard" and thus behavior and support is to be expected to be inconsistent. `Quote: Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user.` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: Ok, but even using `transform: scale(0.9)` the problem with Tooltip continues, and of all the resources, Tooltip is the only one that has a problem

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform